# Experimental fractional scaling to values other than 125, 150, 175 percent

Tags: xorg, display, scaling

I have experimental fractional scaling enable by setting `['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']` as the option for `org.gnome.mutter.experimental-features`. This allows to set a scale of 100%, 125%, 150%, 175% or 200% in the display setting options. This is nice and seems to work well.

Out of curiosity: Is there any way then, to change that scale even to different values like 112.5% or 163% or below 100%?

I know there are some other methods to scale the display like xrandr or scaling the text sizes etc. and I am not asking for those. I would instead like to know, if we can directly set the value defined by the display settings option for "Scale" to a different value.

Comment: Curious to side effects of your fractional scaling. Although experimental features are there, Several libraries are not ready for it, like `Gdk.Window.get_scale_factor()` specifically is of type int: https://valadoc.org/gdk-3.0/Gdk.Window.get_scale_factor.html

Comment: @JacobVlijm: To be honest, I only had a fraction other than 100% enabled for a few minutes or so until I decided that I couldn't find the right fit for my display. Would love to try it longer though.